# Failed to open disk file image Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (...) Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (...)

Tags: virtualbox

Because of some internal errors, the `vdi` file got corrupted, because of which, the header of the `vdi` file has become invalid.

Virtual box is not allowing to attach VDI even to another newly created machine.
I am getting following **error** :-

> *failed to open disk file image Result Code:  VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005) Component:  MediumWrap Interface:  IMedium
>   {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} Callee:  IVirtualBox
>   {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} Callee RC: 
>   VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)*

Answer (score 1):

You can repair the header with this command:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands repairhd -format VDI yourfile.vdi
```

Comment: 'VBoxManage' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: In Windows, you can find the command here: https://serverfault.com/questions/365423/how-to-run-vboxmanage-exe. In MacOS, you will find it under `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/MacOS`. In Linux it depends somewhat on the distribution but most seem to put it under the usual `/usr/bin` location nowadays.

Comment: I get VBoxManage: error: VDI: Error reading pre-header in 'Win10_22H2_Dutch_x64.iso'
VBoxManage: error: Error code VERR_EOF at /build/virtualbox-EnukRN/virtualbox-6.1.36-dfsg/src/VBox/Storage/VDI.cpp(2936) in function int vdiRepair(const char*, PVDINTERFACE, PVDINTERFACE, uint32_t)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution for this problem to try if you have not already tried this:-
If you are using Windows 10 and if you are fine with losing some of your recent data then a simple 'First Aid' solution for this is :-
        **Go to your virtual box vdi file, right click on it and select 'Restore to previous version'. Again attach that vdi and you are done!**

Comment: I have no previous version to restore

Answer (score -1):

answering the above about posting the command VBoxManage internalcommands repairhd -format VDI yourfile.vdi

I figured out that my shell/cmd wont recognize that as a command either. you need to put ./ before vbox manage. so it looks like "./VBoxManage internalcommands repairhd -format VDI yourfile.vdi" without the quotes. i cant attest to that command working as i havent tried it yet, im about to. I just know that for some reason I have to add ./ before vboxmanage commands for them to work.